# Get balance in sqlite3

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'd like to get the balance from a 'debit' table given an Id.

For instance:

```
User                      Debit                          

id   |  name              user_from  | user_to   | value  

1    | John               1          |    2      | 13.23          
2    | Marie              1          |    2      | 20          
3    | Peter              2          |    1      | 53
                          1          |    3      | 2.45
```

I'm John, so I'd like to check my balance to other people.

John's balance = +20.23 (to Marie's)
John's balance = -2.45  (to Peter's)

I'm using sqlite 3 for android !

I have created a SQLFIDDLE to see if it helps ! Link: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/807449/1/0)

Thank you very much for your time and help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use correlated subqueries to compute the subtotals for each user:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       (SELECT TOTAL(value)
        FROM Debit
        WHERE user_from = User.id
          AND user_to   = 1) -
       (SELECT TOTAL(value)
        FROM Debit
        WHERE user_to   = User.id
          AND user_from = 1) AS amount
FROM User
WHERE amount <> 0;

id          name        amount    
----------  ----------  ----------
2           Marie       19.77     
3           Peter       -2.45
```

Comment: I think it's close but not yet there. I changed your query (according to fiddle in my question), changing variables name and taking out the 'where' clause, 'cause it was giving column amount not found. So, here is how it looks now: SELECT id,
       name,
       (SELECT sum(d_value)
        FROM Debit
        WHERE d_from = User.id
          AND d_to   = 1) -
       (SELECT sum(d_value)
        FROM Debit
        WHERE d_to   = User.id
          AND d_from = 1) AS amount
FROM USER; But if you run the fiddle again, you will see that marcao value is null, which is not true, cause Rata owes him.

Comment: Oh, and I changed total to sum, cause total doesnt't exist. Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something like this for the money you owe people (not subtracting money that they owe you): `SELECT SUM(value) FROM debit WHERE user_from = (SELECT id FROM User WHERE name=‘John’)`

UPDATE: I haven't tested any of this but try this out and just do your subtraction after you have the 2 columns.
`SELECT SUM(value) AS 'owes' FROM debit WHERE user_from = (SELECT id FROM User WHERE name=‘John’) GROUP BY user_from
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(value) AS 'owed' FROM debit WHERE user_to = (SELECT id FROM User WHERE name=‘John’) GROUP BY user_to`

Comment: Thanks for answering me. That is simple and works, but I really need the balance !

Comment: Edited my question with a SQLFiddle (including your sql above which didn't work btw). Thanks

Comment: Cool web-app. It looks like its returning the owes in the first row and owed in the second, so you still just subtract them in code (not SQL).